# Entitiy framework core log transaction commit / rollback

Tags: logging, transactions, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using ef core in asp.net core app, enabled logging, and in my logs I can see every query my app do against db.

the problem is that for every transaction I can see in logs:

> [Debug] Beginning transaction with isolation level 'Unspecified'.

but I can't see later in logs any indication if this transaction committed, or rollback.

Is exists any config to do it **automatically**?

---

I'm using serilog with this configuration:

in startup.cs constructor:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
            .CreateLogger();
```

in configure method:

```
loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        loggerFactory.AddSerilog();
```

Comment: Can you please share logging configuration?

Comment: @Sanket logging configuration added